# trouble installing haskell on mac

Tags: haskell

So, I am eager to learn haskell and thought of setting my mac (mavericks) for the same..
I downloaded the package from :https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html
but when I try to run `ghci` 
I get this

```
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: libiconv.dylib (dlopen(libiconv.dylib, 9): image not found)
```

and then it just exits?

Comment: Try `ghci -v3` so it gives you more information. Also, try compiling a simple test program with `ghc -v3 --make <file>`

Comment: If you have installed an iconv lib from macports or the like, you'll need to remove that from your library paths -- it is incompatible with the system iconv that GHC is linked against.

If you only want it "locally" gone when working in GHC, you can add an extra-lib-dir: /usr/lib to the cabal config file, and that may work around this.

Answer (score 0):

The Haskell Platform has been a great boon in starting Haskell for a long time, but is known to not always work for all versions of system libraries and platforms. In this case, it looks like you're missing a common library to handle character encodings (libiconv).

One alternative for installing a working version of ghc/ghci and working with Haskell is a newer project - the [Haskell Tool Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack). This is a program that can be used to automatically download and configure GHC and Haskell libraries on a per project basis. In your case, one of its features is a reduced dependence on global state; every new project makes sure to install a version of GHC and libraries that are known to work with your project and its configuration. You can find more documentation about it [here](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README.html).

Comment: See my comment about the lib iconv issue. Recommending to change tools without understanding the underlying issue is typically of no help...

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that your paths don't point to an alternate libiconv beyond the system standard.

If you *can* run ghci under sudo it may well be that you have the problem described here:

[Requiring sudo to run ghci on OSx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958245/requiring-sudo-to-run-ghci-on-osx)