# Requiring sudo to run ghci on OSx

Tags: macos, haskell, gcc, cabal, ghci

I've installed the Haskell platform on my OSX (Yosemite).

When I try to execute the ghci, the following error occurs:

```
GHCi, version 7.8.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: libiconv.dylib (dlopen(libiconv.dylib, 9): image not found)
```

If I execute using sudo (sudo ghci), it runs normally. The same behavior occurs with cabal.

I've tried to install using the default installer, using homebrew and using the script provided by Yann Esposito (http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Safer-Haskell-Install/), without changes in this behavior. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using Homebrew with `sudo`?

Comment: No... I've used only `brew install ghc`. The problem occurs when I use the installer provided by [haskell.org](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/osx) too.

Comment: Try removing that package first (verify that `ghc` no longer exists) and then installing using Homebrew.

Comment: Already did that. First, I've tried with homebrew, without success. Then, I've tried with the installer. And, after some search, I've tried using the Yann Esposito script. In all cases, the sudo problem persists.

Comment: Does Homebrew install GHC 7.10 instead of 7.8? That’d be a start.

Comment: Yes, it installed the 7.10... But the installer provided by haskell.org that I've used contains the 7.8 version. The script that I've mentioned also use 7.8 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've discovered the answer:

The problem is with my DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH. The value was defined to the directory of my POSTGRESQL bin folder. So, I've appended the recommended values pointed by the man page of dyld (man dyld), reloaded my .bash_profile and now my ghci, cabal and ghc are working smoothly.

The recommended value is:
    "$HOME/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib"

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same problem, and this fixed it.